# What is XAP Deployer?

Tags: lumia

I don't know anything is about  XAP Deployer, I just found it [here](http://windowsphonehub.in/apps/wp8-xap-deployer-2-0-pc-tool-deploy-wp8-xap-device/) while browsing on Internet. Someone please tell me what exactly it is and why it is using?

Comment: The title says "Pc Tool to Deploy Wp8 Xap to device". That seems pretty self-explanatory to me - it's a program for installing apps in XAP format to a Windows Phone 8 device from a PC.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is an Application Deployment tool in Windows Phone 8 SDK which allows developers to deploy and test their apps. However, it allows deploying only one app at a time. The tool you've mentioned supports multiple apps at a time.

**Note:** Both the above programs require that your phone be developer unlocked (which can be done only if you have a Windows Phone developer account) They have no particular use for the general consumer.